# How do I create index inside a procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PROD_SEL
(
  A_N  IN NUMBER,
  AA_N OUT NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  CREATE INDEX NUM_TABLE ON EMP(EMP_NUM);
END PROD_SEL
```

I have this code. How do I create the index inside the procedure properly?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the procedure? Normally indexes are just created once by the DBA. If the index already exists, you'll get an error.

Comment: You shouldn't have `PROD_SEL` after `END`.

Comment: @Barmar it is required on my assignment's instruction. I create an index separately and it works. No I delete it to include inside my procedure and it doesn'tt work

Comment: What database server platform is this for? Microsoft SQL Server, or MySQL, or something different?

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE` is a **DDL** (data definition language) construct and you can't have those inside each other like that.

Typically, if you want to do that, you would execute the '`CREATE INDEX...`' just like you would execute any dynamic `SQL`.

If the index is meant to be temporary and removed after the process, you often see the `CREATE`, then `EXEC` of a procedure, then `DROP` the index.

I would be careful here with the execution plan for the procedure not being aware of the index at all.

Comment: I don't see this mentioned in [Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

Comment: @Barmar It has nothing to do with stored procedures per se.  CREATE has to be the first statement in a batch.

Comment: I assume this answer (as well as the question) is for SQL Server, not MySQL?  Both tags on the question and I think I just read the whole thing assuming mysql and scrarching my head pretty hard.  Maybe @Barmar, too?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it basically applies to all sql dialects

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot There's no sql-server tag on the question. `sql` != `sql-server`

Comment: You're right. I expected to see it and saw what I was looking for, even though it isn't there.  Syntactically, the code in the question is invalid for MySQL, and for MySQL,  this answer isn't correct -- there's no such limitation.  Stored procs can do DDL.  Also in MySQL, stored procedures don't really have an execution plan *per se* -- each client thread invoking a proc does its own initial interpretation individually in the context of the current state of the database the first time that thread invokes the proc.